Why won't my function capture the value of my input element?
I'm working on a freeCodeCamp Javascript project and I currently need to obtain the value given by the user on my input element. I'm practically certain I have my code correct, yet when testing it on freeCodeCamp or in a Code Pen I created the value keeps returning as undefined.
let cash = document.getElementById("cash").value;

const purchaseBtn = document.getElementById("purchase-btn");

purchaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {console.log(cash)});


This line:
const cash = document.getElementById('cash').value;

is getting the value from the element immediately. Instead you want to cache only the element, and then log it's value when the event handler is called.


const cash = document.getElementById('cash');

const purchaseBtn = document.getElementById('purchase-btn');

purchaseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {console.log(cash.value)});
<input id="cash">
<button type="button" id="purchase-btn">Click me</button>




Finally makes sense. Now it's obvious. Thank you.

listener are using other context to render value so the var cash is undefined for the listener execution
correction
const purchaseBtn = document.getElementById("purchase-btn");
    purchaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let cash = document.getElementById("cash").value;
        console.log(cash
    );
});


You are using arrow functions, they are out of your main context, you can use anonymous functions.
"Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to this, arguments, or super, and should not be used as methods."
from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
